# Drivepool alternative for Ubuntu

Tags: nas

I'm trying to setup my own (home) NAS. I don't want RAID, I want to use a more flexible form:

- Mix and match harddrives (now I have 4x 2gb, but for sure when I upgrade I don't want to buy 4 new ones at the same time)
- Some form of duplication (not backup, but something safer than JBOD)
- Duplication of selected folders

I've tried Windows Server 2012 R2 with Stablebit Drivepool (looks very good and works simple).
Now I also want to try it with Ubuntu but I have a hard time finding out what kind of software is available for this?

I saw Greyhole (but has a bad review: http://zornsoftware.codenature.info/blog/why-i-ditched-raid-and-greyhole-for-mhddfs.html)

Any other ways to do this? Or applications?

Comment: Or, like the article says, use `mhddfs`. But Greyhole might actually do what you want.

Comment: This is exactly what greyhole is for, so I would use that.  I can't get it to work on Ubuntu, though

Answer (score 2):

You should use [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) and a cloning cron script.

I am going to assume this setup for you:

- 4 drives for LVM and file storage.
- External USB drive for backups. (at `/dev/sdf1`)
- No duplication -- use `dd` to completely clone as necessary.

### LVM

---

You need to first set up LVM. This diagram is a good example:

[image]

Use a hard drive, and assign each to a LVM folder such as `/lvm` or whatever. [This article is very good for describing LVM](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm). I recommend reading it for a better and more detailed LVM introduction.

First off, partition all storage drives, but **do not add a partition scheme! Use unallocated as the partition type.** I will assume that your storage partitions are `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdc1`, `/dev/sdd1`, and `/dev/sde1`. Your installation will be at `/dev/sda1`.

Next, you need to make the drivers LVM-ready:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1
```

Once that is done, you want to group those drives:

```
vgcreate homeNAS /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1
```

This creates a group called "homeNAS" that conains all of the above drives.

Next, create the Logical Volume:

```
lvcreate --name share homeNAS
```

Create the filesystem:

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/homeNAS/share
```

Once this is done, run the following to create the `lvm` folder:

```
mkdir /lvm/
```

Mount it using:

```
mount /dev/homeNAS/share /lvm
```

To mount it on every boot, add the following to the end of your `/etc/fstab`. Make a backup!!

```
/dev/homeNAS   /lvm     ext3       rw,noatime    0 0
```

***Note that the above guide for LVM is very basic, and is not meant for fancy things. Read the linked article for a much more detailed explanation.***

### Cron Script

---

First off, get an external disc drive. It should be plenty big for storing all of your files. It should be able to hold 1.5x the size of your entire LVM partition (ie, 500GB HDD = 750GB backup).

I will assume your drive has one partition (`ext4` at `/dev/sdf1`, which is mounted at `/media/backup`)

Create a shell script named `lvm-backup.sh` in `/etc/lvm-scripts/` like this:

```
cp /lvm/folder1/ /media/backup/lvm/folder1
cp /lvm/folder2/ /media/backup/lvm/folder2
cp /lvm/folder3/ /media/backup/lvm/folder3
cp /lvm/folder4/ /media/backup/lvm/folder4
```

What this'll do is copy the specified folders to the backup drive. You should not clone directly, as that takes forever and can be detrimental to your system.

Quickly run:

```
chown root:root /etc/lvm-scripts/lvm-backup.sh
chmod +x /etc/lvm-scripts/lvm-backup.sh
```

To run the backup nightly at midnight, add this to your `/etc/crontab`:

```
00 00 * * * sh /etc/lvm-scripts/lvm-backup.sh
```

If you want more specific control of when to run the script, see [this Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) on Cron.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I've just looking into LVM and what I see that if one device fails in the LVM group, the whole group fails. So that will mean that I have to setup 2 drive dedicated for LVM and 2 for backup. If that's the case I can better use RAID (I think). I'st there something flexable where I can say: I have 4 drives, 8 tb total. And I want folder x,y,z duplicated. This will mean that I'm very flexable how I use my storage and don't have it set in stone 2 drives for that and 2 for this.

Comment: The nice thing about LVM is you can disassemble/reassemble the system and change it at any time. You can add/remove LVM part drives easily. So, [if a drive is pre-fail, just remove it from the LVM group and re-assemble it](http://ds9a.nl/lvm-howto/HOWTO/cvs/lvm-howto/output/lvm-howto-6.html). That's really the only problem with LVM, you need to be observant to things happening.